# Programmatically printing dynamic tabular data using Visual Studio 2008 C#

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2008, printing

I am planning to write an application to automate generation of package slips. The idea is that the application would pick up customer order details from the database (say every morning) and generate package slips for them which could be printed out with the click of a button. 
I would like to be able to either print one package slip per page or (in order to save on paper) maximum 2 (if there is enough space left to fit both). I would also prefer to have an option of print preview before printing.
The package slips use a table with some columns spanning over multiple columns above/below. 
Not so important at this point, but a need may arise to be able to export the daily package slips generated by the application to word or PDF.
What is the best way to achieve this?

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure if it would work in your case.  But most of what you are asking to do can be achieved using [iTextSharp](http://sourceforge.net/projects/itextsharp/) to generate a PDF file dynamically.  Because it would generate a PDF you would get a lot of your requirements for free (such as printing, print preview etc).  However, not sure about going from PDF to Word.  Worth considering though as iTextSharp has good support for tabular data.